# I cant seem to find the correct way to index the mean of a previous vector

Tags: r, indexing

I am currently working on a homework problem that is requiring me to index the mean of a previous vector into a new vector. While selecting the mean of the previous vector the instructor wants us to only select the elements that are +- 2 of the said mean. Please see the question below.

From rnorm.vector, select only the elements with values within ±2 standard deviations of
the mean. Assign this new vector to a variable rnorm.select.vector and display the vector.

I have tried using [] and other indexing criterias

```
// Normal distribution of 30 numbers with a mean of 25 and Standard Deviation of 2.5

rnorm.vector <- rnorm(30, mean = 25, sd = 2.5)

// logical vector 

rnorm.logical.vector <- (rnorm.vector >= 25)
rnorm.logical.vector

// +- 2.5 of standard Deviation

rnorm.select.vector <-
```

I cant seem to get a proper outcome without an error

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you get exactly?

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit: test <- 1:5; test[test <= 4 & test >= 2]. Instead of finding values below 4 and above 2, you need to find values above mw + 2sd and below mw - 2sd

Comment: So I have tried rnorm.select.vector <- [(mean(r.norm.vector, +- 2) it is stating that there is an incorrect bracket used

Comment: I think you are allready close to the solution and i hope this link will help you solve the last few bits: https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/logical-indexing.html - if not, we will find another way :)

Comment: the problem here is im not trying to create a logical vector but one that has numerical values stored

Comment: I think what the professor wants is the rnorm distribution used but only select the elements that are ± 2 of the mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i like cats a lot i try to give a little example on how to use a logical vector to select desired elements from an existing vector (that could be cat-names, random numer etc.)

```
# i got a list of my cats name
my_cats_names <- c("Boby", "Tara", "Petzi", "Felix", "Mauzi", "Schnurrli")
# and a coresponding list with my cats weight
my_cats_weight <- c(8, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5)
# so Boby has 8kg, Tara 7 and so on

# During last night someone has stolen my ham, and im suspecting one of my cats to be the thief. 
# Since it was a big ham im pretty sure it needs a cat of at least 6kg to steal and eat it,
# so i want to select all my cats that are 6kg or more from my list. 

which_one_is_over_6_kg_logical_vector <- my_cats_weight >= 6
which_one_is_over_6_kg_logical_vector
# > which_one_is_over_6_kg_logical_vector
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# This result tells me, that the first one in the list is over 6kg, the second one not the 3rd one is over and so on

# Now i can use the logical vector to select only those elements from my list, that fullfill my constraint (beeing over 6kg)
my_cats_over_6kg <- my_cats_names[which_one_is_over_6_kg_logical_vector]
my_cats_over_6kg
# > my_cats_over_6kg
# [1] "Boby"  "Petzi"
# im pretty sure it was Boby or Petzi

# So by creating a logical vector we can select items from an existing vector if they fullfill our constraint
```

Instead a vector of catnames you got a vector of numbers for which you can calculate a mean and a standard deviation. 
Instead of selecting cats over 6kg you whant numbers below mean(your_vector) - 2*sd(your_vector) and numbers above mean(your_vector) + 2*sd(your_vector).

I hope all the cats will help a bit and not cause additional confusion :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used this to help me figure somethings out with my own code. 

I used rnorm.se;ect.vector <- rnorm.vector[+- 2] and it seemed to work idk if I am pulling just the numbers with a sd of ± 2 but it seems to not throw any errors

Comment: Im not sure if it works, but you can check your results. All elements in select.vector habe to be lower than mean(rnorm.vector) - 2*sd(rnorm.vector) or bigger than mean(rnorm.vector) + 2*sd(rnorm.vector). Is this the case?

Comment: Yes this is the case I had to adhere to, ± 2 sd of the original mean from the first vector I created (which was 25)